# How to install yarn and npm on a PHP docker image (symfony 4 project)

Tags: php, docker, symfony, npm, yarnpkg

Im working on a symfony 4/posgresql project. Im using docker toolbox.

I need to install webpack encore bundle on symfony, but in order to do this, i need to add yarn and npm to my project. Somebody told me i should add theses 2 installations on my php docker container, but i don't know which command to add (im a linux/docker beginner).

This is my docker-compose.yaml :

```
 
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - 'boeki_database:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
 
  database_pg_admin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
        - "8001:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: root@root.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
       
  application:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/project
    ports:
        - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/project:rw,cached
      - ./docker/http/000-default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:rw,cached
 
volumes:
  boeki_database: {}
```

And this is my Dockerfile :

```
 
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libpq-dev g++ zlib1g-dev libicu-dev vim git zip
 
#GD
RUN apt-get update && \
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  libfreetype6-dev \
  libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
  libpng-dev \
  libzip-dev \
  poppler-utils
 
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg && \
  docker-php-ext-install -j "$(nproc)" gd pdo_pgsql
 
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql intl zip opcache
 
RUN pecl install redis && echo "extension=redis.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-redis.ini
 
RUN a2enmod rewrite
 
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: As i said, i don't know how docker work, and i don't really have time to learn how it work. Im just asking for some help. Is that hard to make this installation or he take few lines ?

Comment: I tried some command, like curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
 echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list and apt-get update && apt-get install yarn, but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't know where to start, there is a lot of informations on internet, but i I can't sort.

Answer (score 6):

according to https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#debian-stable which provides some commands to follow, adding the following to your dockerfile *should* work (disclaimer: I'm not extremely familiar with docker)

```
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y yarn
```

(the -y removes the questions)

Comment: Thanks mate, that was almost the solution. Theses commands worked : RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update &&  apt-get  install -y yarn

Comment: Had to remove all "sudo" and change on the 3rd line "apt" for "apt-get"

Comment: @JamesSTANDBRIDGE updated my answer to reflect your changes so it may help others. glad it worked for you ;o)